# Node js capture keyboard press and mouse movement (not on Web Browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, keyboard, keypress

I'm trying to make a program using node js that will capture key press and mouse movement . Not on web browser . It's one kind of keylogger type for my personal project . I tried robotjs but it's need many dependency to run . Is there any simple way to do that .
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keylogger

Comment: Yes , this package totally garbage . It only store what you typed on terminal . nothing else

Comment: What have you tried so far? This makes it easy for people to give you an answer.

Comment: I have been googling to find any package for node to capture keyboard and mouse but nothing found . only one package meet with my requirement and that is [robotjs](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs) but it's need too many dependency and not possible for me to implement for my project :(

Comment: Hi! I'm looking for very similar solution. I need to log user activity for Time Tracker app. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am on the same boat. While Robotjs allows you to control user's mouse & keyboard, I need a tool which would help me to record user's movement

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you need global key hook.
Try to use [iohook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook) module

```
'use strict';
const ioHook = require('iohook');

ioHook.on("mousemove", event => {
  console.log(event);
  // result: {type: 'mousemove',x: 700,y: 400}
});
ioHook.on("keydown", event => {
  console.log(event);
  // result: {keychar: 'f', keycode: 19, rawcode: 15, type: 'keypress'}
});
//Register and stark hook 
ioHook.start();
```

It is cross platform native module, works on Windows, Linux, MacOS

Comment: cant run this on windows

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the keypress module? https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress

Examples from the repo for KEY:

```
var keypress = require('keypress');
// use decoration to enable stdin to start sending ya events 
keypress(process.stdin);
// listen for the "keypress" event
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {
    console.log('got "keypress"', key);
    if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
      process.stdin.pause();
    }
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

Examples from the repo for Mouse:
    var keypress = require('keypress');

```
// make `process.stdin` begin emitting "mousepress" (and "keypress")    events
keypress(process.stdin);

// you must enable the mouse events before they will begin firing
keypress.enableMouse(process.stdout);

process.stdin.on('mousepress', function (info) {
  console.log('got "mousepress" event at %d x %d', info.x, info.y);
});

process.on('exit', function () {
  // disable mouse on exit, so that the state
  // is back to normal for the terminal
  keypress.disableMouse(process.stdout);
});
```

Comment: yes I tried it but this is not what i'm looking for , I just want something similar to real key logger that will actually track my key press/release no matter where i type and click

Comment: The `keypress` module is kinda broken too.

Comment: Note that this package has conflicts with other packages like `prompts`, which will capture key presses twice if `keypress` is used