# How can I get keyboard input outside of the Node.js process window?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a tool that needs hotkeys to function. I'm currently using the `keypress` module to get input, however It's not receiving the input outside of the terminal window. Any easy solutions for this?

Comment: Which platform(s) are you planning to target?

Comment: @Mathyn just windows 10

Comment: Try https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook

Comment: ill give it a shot, ty

Comment: There's sample code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974712/node-js-capture-keyboard-press-and-mouse-movement-not-on-web-browser

Comment: nope it still wont work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node js capture keyboard press and mouse movement (not on Web Browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974712/node-js-capture-keyboard-press-and-mouse-movement-not-on-web-browser)

Comment: ah i see why it hadnt worked earlier. i was checking if the keychar property was f12, but this uses specific numbers. works now, but how can i make iohook not log [this](https://microzi.glitch.me/images/screenshots/257se.png) when i run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to post this before but I got everything working by simply using the iohook module. Thank you all! Here is a sample code for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442293/13549031